# How to update maps of type map<string, vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need to update maps of type `map<string, vector<int>>`. I created this function:

```
// INPUT: d - original map, key - key to be updated, 
//        new_val - value that will be appended to d[key]
// OUTPUT: vector<int> which is the updated value of d[key]
vector<int> update_value(map<string, vector<int>> d, string key, int new_val) {
    map<string, vector<int>>::iterator it = d.find(key);
    vector<int> current_vec;
    int prev_len = current_vec.size();
    if (it != d.end()) {
        current_vec = it->second;
        current_vec.push_back(new_val);
        return current_vec;
    }
    assert(prev_len + 1, current_vec.size()); // this fails
    return current_vec;
}
```

I always get the assertion statment failed.

What is the correct method to do this?

Comment: Regardless of any assert issues, this function won't update the map because you pass by value rather than reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assert will always fail since the `current_vec` will always be empty in case the `key` is not found in the map. I suggest you remove this temporary vector, and you handle the case were the `key` is not found in another way (e.g. insertion).

You also need to pass your structure `d` by reference in order for it to get updated

```
vector<int>& update_value(map<string, vector<int>>& d, string key, int new_val) {
    map<string, vector<int>>::iterator it = d.find(key);
    if (it != d.end()) {
        it->second.push_back(new_val);
    }
    else {
         vector<int> v;
         v.push_back(new_val);
         d.insert(make_pair(key, v));
         return d[key];
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Comment: The keys are not there by default. What should I do in this case? I am thinking of adding `d[key] = new_vector;` there

Comment: I think it should be `return d[key]` and not `return d[key]->second`.

Answer (score 2):

If I got this right, it seems the update will take place only if the key actually exists, as the update code is only present in the the body of the `if`.

On the other hand, the `assert` will get checked only when the condition `it != d.end()` (i.e., the key is present in the map) does not hold (otherwise the final `return` statement in the `if` body will cause the end of the function).

As a result, when reaching `assert` you know `current_vec.size()` (as thus `prev_len`) to be `0` and so the assert reduces to `assert(1, 0)`, which is false.

As a side note, since you are passing your map by value, the update you make will not reflect in the original dictionary. Similarly, notice that you are also copying the `std::vector` out of the map.